# Where is the Set product new from date found in database?

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I am a newbie to magento and would like to know where the "set product new from date" values for each product are found in the databse table and the column name. I checked with the catalogrule_product. There is a column named from_time, I am not sure is this is the right table or if there are any other table related to this.

Answer (score 1):

Magento follows EAV database structure. In database, you will find **eav_attribute** table.

In there search for attribute_code = 'news_from_date' and attribute_code = 'news_to_date' and note down ids of these attributes.

Now go to **catalog_product_entity_datetime** table and search for attribute_id =  and entity_id =

I think, your query is resolved now. If you have any confusion then please ask.

Comment: I do not have enough reputations to vote up, since i think no one likes to vote up for my question

Answer (score 0):

Attribute name is : news_from_date

$code = 'news_from_date'

now using $attributeId= getAttributeId($code );

$entity_id= $product->getId();

Now as stated above query :  select * from catalog_product_entity_datetime wher attribute_id = $attributeId and entity_id = $entity_id